# Adding fields in Rails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I Have an author model in my project and want to add another field to the form so the the author can have their name email and avatar, I would like the author to also be able to insert some content at the same time.
1, when I add another field to my form that is ok.
2, do I add the t.string "content" in the schema file? as this hasn't worked(I have ran rake db:migrate) 
3,I have added the t.string :content in the migrate file for the authors (this has stayed there but hasn't done anything)
4, Should I be going into the ruby console and adding the info there somehow so the database knows about the content field?

I only want to add another field to the database and the program not return :
     `` undefined method `content' for Author:0x00000100c5cc08
Extracted source (around line #24): ``

21:   div 
22:   div class="field"
23:     <%= f.label :content %>
24:     <%= f.text_area :content %>
25:   div
26:   div class="actions"
27:     <%= f.submit %>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/authors/new.html.erb

Rails.root: /Users/r/Sites/RailsProjects/as

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never edit schema.rb file directly - it's auto-generated from your database.

Adding `t.string :content` to you migration file will modify the model in the way you want. Did you run the migration, though? Use rake db:rollback and rake db:migrate to re-apply the migration (assuming it's the last in your set). Beware you'll lose your authors data when you do that.

Alternatively, you could just create a new migration to add the column, like so:

```
def self.up
  add_column :authors, :content, :string
end

def self.down
  remove_column :authors, :content
end
```

Then run rake db:migrate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to add that field is go to command prompt and type as follows

---

ruby script/generate igration AddContentToAuthor content:string
**then press enter. after that you need to done database migration you can do it as follows

---

rake db:migrate 
**then press enter now your code will work correctly